# Access to the gzclient_camera in a world plugin

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to take a picture from a world that I create using a worldPlugin.
For practical reasons, I'd like to take the picture at the end of the world plugin.

I noticed that when a gzclient is open, a camera "gzclient_camera" is created. I was hoping to select this camera from the world plugin and then take my picture by doing :

```
    parent->GetByName("gzclient_camera")->SetPose(anIgnitionPose);
    parent->GetByName("gzclient_camera")->SaveFrame(imgName);
```

With parent the WorldPtr to my world.

But it seems that it doesn't work. I was wondering if there is a way to select the gzclient_camera from the worldPtr.
The API seems to say that  "The world provides access to all other object within a simulated environment" but at the same time PrintEntityTree shows only models and the sun.

Thanks for anyone that can help.

PS : I guess it's possible to solve it by creating a sensor plugin and to calling it from the worldPlugin but it seems a little bit over complicated for probably 2 lines of code.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19692/access-to-the-gzclient_camera-in-a-world-plugin/) by [TTDM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3017/ttdm/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 88 on 2018-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

World plugins run on `gzserver`, which is a different process from `gzclient`. So you won't be able to get a pointer to the user camera, which runs in the client.

You could add a camera sensor to the world and  take the screenshot with that instead. And since that would live in sensor land, rather than physics land, I'd use something like this to get it:

```
auto camera = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<sensors::CameraSensor>(
    sensors::SensorManager::Instance()->GetSensor(cameraName));
```

That's still 2 lines ;)

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TTDM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3017/ttdm/) on 2018-06-13**:
My bad for not seeing your first point. Thanks a lot for the line to retrieve a sensor in a world plugin.
Just for the exactitude, there is a little typo, it's 'std::dynamic_pointer_castsensors::CameraSensor'  and then to use the rendering, the functions should be called as : 'camera->Camera()->SaveFrame(name)'
Thanks again

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-06-13**:
Thanks for pointing out the typo, it's fixed

**Comment by [TTDM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3017/ttdm/) on 2018-06-13**:
And if some readers wonder how to add a camera in a world plugin, I did it in adding a model that includes a camera using the World function: InsertModelString. See an exemple of the sdf  here :http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=camera_save&cat=sensors

**Comment by [TTDM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3017/ttdm/) on 2018-06-18**:
I also want to add that a simple SaveFrame Call is not enough to save a frame. It creates the exact same issue as here: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18277/rendering-error-of-camera-sensor-partially-gray-image/ . I'm looking at the other rendering functions and I will post an answer there if I find how to do it properly.